# Is it possible to do OAuth authentication identifying yourself as someone else?

Tags: facebook, web-services, oauth, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I'm writing a web app that connects to social media services (Facebook, LinkedIn, etc.) to collect a person's contacts for publicity purposes. The person **wants** this service and is paying for it, and recognizes my company and app name when it pops an OAuth dialog that says `Contact Manager from Company Y would like to access your connections. Do you want to allow this?`

However, now I want to license my app to a publicity **agency** which would use the app to manage contacts for their *clients*. The app would then have to send an OAuth request to their client, except that the client hired the **agency** not **me**, and they won't recognize **my** company and app name.

So the question is: can my app identify itself on behalf of the *agency*, and say to the user `Contact Manager from Your PR Agency would like to access your connections. Do you want to allow this?` so that the person reading this will know that the request is coming from someone they know, instead of me, whom they don't know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you will need to register different applications and create application keys for each of your agencies in order to be able to do this, since OAuth providers generally display the application name to the user.

Comment: Ugh, that's not going to be very scalable, but I guess it will be serviceable in the early days. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you could make clear to the users on behalf of which agency your application is authorizing before redirecting... so they will accept to login to your application (domain name).

Comment: I could call the app "Contact Manager by Agency X", but that only works for Agency X, not the many other agencies I want to have. But what I don't get is whether my application can dynamically substitute another name for "Agency X", based on runtime data about which agency is currently using my app to query *their* client for data.

Comment: In order to use OAuth, you generally need to register your application with your provider. It will give you an application key and secret to work with. The problem is that during the login they will generally display the URL (Google) and/or the name (Facebook) of the registered application. No dynamic changing of the displayed information is allowed for security purposes. The same information will always be displayed for a single app. But, if you register multiple apps, you could dynamically change the keys and host your application on the same server.

Comment: This makes sense. I guess I can manually register agencies until such time as the volume becomes a problem. I wonder if there's a way to programmatically register an application. Probably this is much too easy to abuse though.

Comment: I don't know if such possibility is provided by the Google APIs. Facebook probably does not and won't provide - it is my opinion. They could control the abuse for such cases by limiting the volume and controlling the user who registers these applications ...